# How does spy++ find out what is the window at a certain point on the screen?

Tags: c++, winapi, spy++

I am curious how spy++ Finder Tool finds out the window handle for the window over which the mouse is. 
Is there any WIN32 function for getting the handle of the topmost window that occupies a certain pixel on the display?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a [WindowFromPoint()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: since that returns a `HWND`, would `WindowFromPoint` work with windows from another process?

Comment: HWNDs are valid throughout the whole OS, so yes.

Comment: thanks, that's what i was looking for.
I used something like this before: HWND wnd = (HWND)0x....; SendMessage(wnd,...); and it worked fine(it was a window for another application), so i think it works with that handle too. :)

Comment: Technically, HWNDs are valid within a desktop. So you can SendMessage to any HWND on the same desktop as your thread (even if that HWND is running as another user), but not to a HWND on another desktop, or to a HWND in another session on the same computer. (...assuming that the target application isn't running elevated, in which case SendMessage will likely fail; look up UIPI for more info on that case.)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a pretty complete example of how to implement the spy++ finder.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/windowfinder.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There is some nice information on the internals of Spy++ here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/01/16/spy-internals.aspx. It supports DeusAduro's reply, that Spy++ installs global hooks (actually 3 hooks, one of which is WH_CALLWNDPROC).

You can also find some more info on a Spy++-clone here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/windowfinder.aspx.

Also, there should be a download for a very similar app in the SDK here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa231779 but it seems to be broken (no download - like so many links on msdn :( ).

Depending on what you want to get (if it is not a hwnd) you can also get an AutomationElement:

```
System.Windows.Point pt = new System.Windows.Point(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y);
AutomationElement ae = AutomationElement.FromPoint(pt);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`WindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms633558(VS.85)) or [`ChildWindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms632676(VS.85)) API functions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote me on it, but I believe spy++ would install a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook. This then gets sent all the WM_MOUSEMOVE messages before they reach their target windows. Thus as soon as you mouse over a window, spy++ recieves a message telling it which window.

Comment: This is probably not the case: Spy++ likely takes mouse capture (SetCapture()) when you click the crosshair, so it gets the WM_MOUSEMOVE messages as you drag, not the window under the pointer. Spy++ is likely just using WindowFromPoint/ChildWindowFromPoint as it gets the mouse moves - no hooking required.